# Consulta SELECT no reconoce el caracter "ñ" en tabla de mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Estoy realizando una consulta SQL de esta manera:

```
select * from catalogo_proveedor where NOMBREFISCAL LIKE "%IKATECHñ%";
```

en realidad el like que estoy ejecutando existe como registro en la base de datos inclusive como ñ, pero al momento de ejecutar la anterior consulta el resultado es un vacío, al quitar la ñ de la consulta se ejecuta correctamente. La estructura de la tabla consultada es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalogo_proveedor` (
   `IDPROVEEDOR` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `NOMBREFISCAL` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `NOMBRECOMERCIAL` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    KEY `NOMBRECOMERCIAL` (`NOMBRECOMERCIAL`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3772 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

¿Cual puede ser el problema por el cual Mysql no reconoce la "ñ" en la consulta?

Comment: Agrega el charset de la base de datos y el collation de ambos de la base de datos y de la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Me concentraría en verificar:

1. Default Collation.
2. Default CharacterSet.

He trabajado mis BD sin problemas con:

1. Default Collation = utf8.
2. Default CharacterSet = utf_unicode_ci.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas que la columna esté definida como utf8 (si se cambia la definición y ya hay datos guardados, puede haber líos)

```
col_name varchar(10) collate utf8_bin
```

o indicar en la consulta que el campo se debe buscar con encoding utf8:

```
WHERE col_name LIKE '%áéíñ%' collate utf8_bin
```

El collate puede ser ese o `utf8mb4_bin`

Fuente: [SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql)

Comment: Muchas gracias Alfabravo por el aporte. Cuando realizo la consulta con el collate utf8mb4_bin me sale el siguiente mensaje; "is not valid for CHARACTER SET' latin1'". Antes de lanzar el collate hay que ejecutar el alter para modificar el campo?